# Force CRTP inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to detect that a CRTP base class is templated with the exact same class deriving from  base?

I've something like

```
class GeneratedA : public RegisteredEvent<GeneratedA>;
class GeneratedB : public RegisteredEvent<GeneratedB>;
```

which works but is it possible to trigger a compile error if the interface is used like this:

```
class GeneratedB : public RegisteredEvent<GeneratedA>;
```

Thank you

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224838/prevent-user-from-derive-from-incorrect-crtp-base (possible duplicate)

Comment: @javaLover - It is indeed.