# Can concepts be used with CRTP idiom?

Tags: c++, c++20, crtp, c++-concepts

Given following curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) code example:

```
template<typename X>
struct Base {
  X f() const { return X{}; }
};

template<template<typename> typename T>
struct Derived : T<Derived<T>>
{};

const Derived<Base> d0{};
const Derived<Base> d1 = d0.f();
```

I started to wonder whether it is possible to confine, with the use of concepts, possible set of base classes. My idea, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62364832/11810469) assumes use of `requires B<T, Derived<T>>`, where `B` is defined as follows:

```
#include <concepts>

// ...

template<template<typename> typename T, typename X>
concept B = requires (T<X> t)
  {
   { t.f() } -> std::convertible_to<X>;
  };
```

Obviously, I cannot use this form:

```
template<template<typename> typename T> requires B<T, Derived<T>>
struct Derived : T<Derived<T>>
{};
```

because `Derived` in *require-clause* is not yet defined. This:

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
struct Derived requires B<T, Derived<T>> : T<Derived<T>>
{};
```

and this:

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
struct Derived : T<Derived<T>> requires B<T, Derived<T>>
{};
```

don't solve the problem as well.

Is there a way to overcome these difficulties and combine concepts with CRTP?

(I performed tests on GCC 10.0.1.)

Comment: "*Given following curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)*" That's kind of a weird example of the CRTP. The derived class in CRTPs generally *know* what CRTP base classes they're going to use. If this is being done for composition reasons (you intend to inherit from `Derived` in a CRTP manner), then the eventual CRTP base class needs to use the *final* derived class type, not the intermediate type.

Comment: It's also not clear what the point of this would be. If `Derived` is an intermediate class that has no knowledge of what the CRTP base class is doing, it should accept anything. And if `Derived` *knows* what the CRTP base class is doing... then it either knows which class (template) it is using, or it has some idea of what the interface for this template is. And that interface would be a concept that defines the CRTP base class, not the derived one.

Comment: @NicolBolas 1. Maybe I haven't understood your comment, but I don't think my example is weird - I've even seen variadic CRTP and it was fine. 2. In my example I don't want to inherit from `Derived`. 3. I want to explicitly define concept as a layer of abstraction between classes.

Comment: "*I want to explicitly define concept as a layer of abstraction between classes.*" But you don't have classes. Your `Derived` takes a *template*, not a class. And your code is instantiating that template with the type begin defined. You can't constrain a template based on something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what relationship you want to create here. CRTP is typically used to inject behavior into a derived class by inserting members that can access the derived class and/or the derived class can access. Are you trying to impose constraints on the specific things being augmented?

Comment: @NicolBolas In my previous comment I omitted word _template_. My intention is to explicitly define, in one place, minimal interface for base class.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78241558/181238) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read a proposal that proposed to define constraint on class definition. But it is not merged in the standard. So if you want to constrain a class definition the only work-around I know is to use a static assertion in a context where the class is completly defined, so inside member function body:

```
    template <class Base>
struct A: Base 
    {

     A() {
          static_assert(a_concept <A>);
          }
    };
```